# Set image to fullscreen HTML

Tags: android, css, html

I am trying to show an image filling the whole screen, my HTML looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="./res/Default.png" width="100%" height="100%"/>   
    </body>
</html>
```

Now, it looks as it should almost everywhere, but it only fills the upper half of the screen on a "HTC Incredible S". Anyone knows why and/or how it could be repaired?

Comment: Try `style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this by

```
top:0;
left:0; 
position:fixed; 
min-width:100%; //keeps it filling the browser window vertically
min-height:100%; //keeps it filling horizontally
```

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dB7kr/)

[Full screen result](http://jsfiddle.net/dB7kr/embedded/result/)

Comment: Why don't you explain a bit how and why this works? This is a really low quality answer that could work, but doesn't add much value to this site.

Comment: Works!! great, why do you need top, left, and position:fixed for it to work?

Comment: @simpleBob you may figure out difference http://jsfiddle.net/E8QgM/ without top and left 0 and with top and left 0 http://jsfiddle.net/Z7mA8/

Answer (score 2):

This will maximize the image. If the image is larger than the viewport it will overflow but be hidden. You will never get white areas not covered by the image.

```
<body>
    <img src="./res/Default.png"/>   
</body>

body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
img {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bzTNV/2/

Comment: Why don't you explain a bit how and why this works? This is a really low quality answer that could work, but doesn't add much value to this site.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is because the body container is not set to take up 100% of the window.

Example using your code: http://jsfiddle.net/ejTSL/1/

Example with body styled with `width:100%;height:100%;` and img anchored to the browser window: http://jsfiddle.net/9BnGD/2/

Try:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body style="width:100%;height:100%">
        <img src="./res/Default.png" width="100%" height="100%" style="position:fixed;top:0;left:0;/>   
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The image is getting skewed though

Comment: Well it will do, because the window can be an infinite number of width  x hight proportions, depending on the device it is displayed on. Using overflow is another technique, but that was not what was being asked.

Comment: @simpleBob If you post the actual URL to your image then we can help.  Do you just want to show enough of the image to cover the screen, or do you want the entire image to show?

Comment: I want the entire image, stretched (it is an android project, the image is on HDD)

Comment: Then the code in my answer and [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ejTSL/) does that.  Unless you have other elements in your markup that are causing the problem.  Rather than "think" your 'body is at 100%, have you tried actually adding the inline style to your body - then you can be sure that both the width and the height are scaled to 100%

Comment: "I want the entire image, stretched " - the accepted answer does not do that - it crops the image to fit the available window space.

Comment: @PassKit would you let me know how it doesnot do that ? and fiddle in you comment seems not working for me http://jsfiddle.net/9BnGD/

Comment: Whatever works for the poster is accepted, it's not for us to decide. @simpleBob said that he would like the image stretched, your solution crops the image, hiding a significant proportion on the right on a phone screen and on my 27" iMac, leaves whitespace at the bottom because the image is not stretching to fill 100%.

Comment: I now have `<img src="./res/Default.png" width="100%" height="100%" style="top:0;left:0;position:fixed;min-width:100%;min-height:100%;" />`. Does this not stretch the image?

Comment: I mean, it still has `width="100%" height="100%"`

Comment: Your body tag should have style="width:100%;height:100%". By setting min-width you are effectively saying that the image must be AT LEAST the width of the body, but if the image is wider than the body, it will be cropped, not stretched.  Remove the min-width and min-height from the img, then add the style tag to your body and the image should STRETCH 100% in both directions.

Comment: @PassKit it seems to me that min-width is just a redundant attribute since width="100%" already makes sure that the image will be 100% of the body

Comment: Not necessarily true, and different browsers will give one or the other preference. Ideally, you should remove width="100%" and height="100%" and use width:100%;height:100%; in the style attribute. If you use width: then the image will scale, if you user min-width: then you may get cropping at the bottom or right depending on the dimensions of your image E.g. http://jsfiddle.net/ejTSL/4/

Answer (score 0):

I use this simple markup. Just stick it in the html body. It can be modded to use css classes or be created in JQuery. I haven't tested on ALL devices, but I haven't found anything that this isn't responsive and mobile friendly on.

```
<div id="FullscreenDiv" style="z-index:99999;display:none;position:fixed;background-color:black;top:0px;bottom:0;left:0;right:0">
    <div id="FullscreenDivImg" style="position:fixed;background-color:black;background:url(../Content/Images/Example.png) center center no-repeat;background-size:contain;top:10px;bottom:10px;left:10px;right:10px">
    </div>
</div>
```